# Run all test methods via reflection through @Test annotated method in java. different results

Tags: java, unit-testing, methods, junit, reflection

previously i had an issue with running test cases in my project which took very long because each @Test annotation creates a server to run the test method.
so i wrote a method by using java reflection to run all test methods via that method.

let me explain. 
previously it was like this and all test methods worked fine and nothing failed.,

```
Class A{

    @Test
    public void testMethod1(){
        //Do something
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod2(){
        //Do something
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethodn(){
        //Do something
    }
}
```

what i did was like this,

```
Class A{

    @Test
    public void runAllMethods(){
        Method[] methods = ((T)this).getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method m : methods) {
         if (!(m.getName().toString()).contains("runAllMethods")) {
            try {
               m.invoke((T)(this), null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
               //
            }
         }
  }
    }

    public void testMethod1(){
        //Do something
    }


    public void testMethod2(){
        //Do something
    }


    public void testMethodn(){
        //Do something
    }
}
```

After i did like this. some test cases are getting fail.
all the exception error are

```
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: expected:
```

I want to run all test methods via another @Test method.
Could you please someone can help me here?
Thanks

Comment: The problem here is that your tests are written or configured poorly, not that your use case is so special that you need to write an entire custom test runner from scratch.

Comment: Are you doing some heavy duty stuff in your `@Before` method which gets executed before every `@Test` method and slows down the execution?

Comment: Why are you casting your `this` to a non-existing type `T`? And why are you calling `toString()` on a `String` and using `contains` when you actually mean `equals`? Besides that, as the others already mentioned, that looks like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Just changing `@Before` to `@BeforeClass` might help.